# FQL multi-query optmization for events listing

Tags: facebook, fql.multiquery

I am working on a custom Events app in Facebook and have ran into an issue where the response seems quite slow. The slowness mostly relate to trying to search for a page that is associated with an events geographical location. I.e "City, Country". Once such URL would be:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Buenos-Aires-Argentina/106423786059675

I've already determined that it is possible to obtain the page URL for a page like this with the following FQL query:

SELECT page_id, page_url FROM page WHERE name = "Buenos Aires, Argentina" AND type = "CITY"

The type column equals CITY is important, as otherwise other non-relevant pages URLs may be returned.

Anyhow, in order to get all events by a user and display their rsvp status, display information about the venue and also get the geographic places page URL I'm running the following mult-query FQL:

```
[events_query] => SELECT eid, name, pic_square, start_time, end_time, location, description, all_members_count, venue   FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 6747251459 AND start_time > 0)  AND start_time > 0 AND end_time < now() ORDER BY start_time desc LIMIT 5

[rsvp_query] => SELECT eid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM #events_query) AND uid = YOUR_EVENTS_UID

[venue_page_id_query] => SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE page_id IN (SELECT venue.id FROM #events_query)

[venue_info_query] => SELECT page_id, name, page_url, location FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #venue_page_id_query)

[geo_city_country_query] => SELECT name, page_url FROM page WHERE name IN (SELECT concat(location.city, ', ', location.country) FROM #venue_info_query) AND type = "CITY"
```

My problem is that when doing the "geo_city_country_query" the response slows down quite a bit. To approx +5seconds. Without the "geo_city_country_query" query, the response time is approx 1.5sec-2sec.

Is there any way I can get this done faster?

Thanks in advance!